# Comprehension Question about logical operator &&

Tags: javascript

I have a question regarding a code snippet from the `React.js` tutorial. I'm a beginner in JavaScript, so please excuse me if this is a dumb question.

```
function calculateWinner(squares) {
  const lines = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6],
  ];
  for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    const [a, b, c] = lines[i];
    if (squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === squares[c]) {
      return squares[a];
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

The purpose of this function is to evaluate the winner of a tic-tac-toe game. The square argument gets an array of nine values with type of `null`, `"X"` or `"O"`.

Assuming that the first three values of the array are `"X"`, the if-statement would resolve to `"X" && "X" === "X" && "X" === "X"`. This would result in `"X" === "X" === "X"`. So it should return `true`and the player playing with the "X" has won.

But if I try it in JSBin for example, `console.log("X" === "X" === "X")` returns `false`. I just don't get it, because in my opinion `"X"` is equal to `"X"` is equal to `"X"`.

Can anyone explain where my error in reasoning is?

Thank you very much!

Sebastian Beier

Comment: *"This would result in `"X" === "X" === "X"`"* - Um... No it wouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reasoning around the `&&` operator is correct.

The problem is your understanding of the `===` operator. In mathematics you could use equality in the manner you expected (x = x = x) and you would have a correct (true) statement. But in programming it doesn't work like this.

Each operator is evaluated one-by-one.

So you started with:

```
"X" === "X" === "X"
```

This will be evaluated as two separate statements. The operator on the left is evaluated first for this operator (this is known as the [associativity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table) of the operator). You can put brackets around the first statement to make it explicit, like this:

```
("X" === "X") === "X"
```

The statement in the brackets is evaluated, leaving:

```
true === "X"
```

This now evaluates to `false`, because `true` is not equal to `"X"`.

I recommend you **never** try to use the equality operators in this way (`a === b === c`). The same goes for other equality operators such as `!==`. It's not a typical programming pattern and is likely to confuse other programmers in the same way that it confused you.

To test equality of three items, always use the `&&` operator like this: `a === b && b === c`. This makes it clear that each equality test happens one-by-one.

Answer (score 8):

> Assuming that the first three values of the array are "X", the if-statement would resolve to "X" && "X" === "X" && "X" === "X". This would result in "X" === "X" === "X".

No, it would result in `"X" && true && true`:

```
if (squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === squares[c])
//  ^^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//     "X"                 true                          true
```

The `&&`evaluates its left-hand operand and, if that result is *falsy*¹, results in that falsy value. If the left-hand operand's value is *truthy*, `&&` evalutes its right-hand operand and takes that value as its result.

So `"X" && true && true` evalutes to `true && true` which evalutes to `true`.

In contrast, the `===` operator evalutes its left-hand operand, then its right-hand operand, and then its right-hand operand, and compares the result for strict equality (same type and value). It's also left-to-right associative, so `"X" === "X" === "X"` is `("X" === "X") === "X"` which is `true === "X"` which is `false`, because `true` is not strictly equal to `"X"`.

---

¹ "falsy" - When used in a boolean context (for instance, an `if` condition) a value is *falsy* if it coerces to `false`. The falsy values are `0`, `""`, `null`, `undefined`, `NaN`, and of course `false`. All other values are *truthy* — they coerce to `true`.

Answer (score 4):

Because `===` is a binary operator (it works on two operands at a time, only).

```
"X" === "X" === "X"
```

is equivalent to

```
(("X" === "X") === "X")
```

(First, the first `===` is evaluated between the first two operands, then the result is compared to the third operand.)

That is equivalent to

```
true === "X"
```

Which is, of course, `false`.

If you wanted to test the correctness of your logical expression, you would need to replicate it fully, `&&`s and all:

```js
console.log("X" && "X" === "X" && "X" === "X"); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all very much for your answers! They all helped me a lot!

Now I think I got it.

> To test equality of three items, always use the && operator like this: a === b && >b === c.

This is indeed easier to understand than the solution from the React tutorial, at least for me.

Comment: Hi Sebastian, you're welcome (and welcome to Stackoverflow!) Just a tip: it's best not to add new answer just to thank others. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more info.

Comment: Hi Justin, i will do so in the future!